# View is not updated on change in Angular2

Tags: angular

I've started exploring Angular2 (I'm coming with Angular1 and a bit of React background) and I got stuck with a problem.

I want to bind certain keystrokes to actions in my component, so I've decided to use Angular2 lifecycle to bind/unbind actions.

However, if I do something from within a Mousetrap callback, it works, but it's not rendered and a change is not visible until a digest cycle is run.

Do I need to run something explicitly to update a view

Could somebody help me to figure out what is going on?
Any help would be very appreciated.

---

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
const Mousetrap = require('mousetrap');

@Component({
  template: `<div>
    Video template: Mode {{ mode }}
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="mode"/>
  </div>`
})
export class Video {

  public mode: number;

  constructor() {
    this.mode = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('hello Video component');
    Mousetrap.bind('d', () => console.log('this.mode=', this.mode));
    Mousetrap.bind('i', () => this.incrementMode()); // doesn't work

    this.incrementMode(); // works
    this.incrementMode(); // works
    setTimeout(() => this.incrementMode(), 4000); // works

  }

  incrementMode() {
    console.log('incMode', this.mode++);
  };

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('bye bye Video component');
    Mousetrap.unbind(['d', 'i']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although @Günter's answer is absolutely correct I want to propose a different solution.

The problem with `Mousetrap` library is that it creates its instance **outside of the angular [zone](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)** (see [here](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/blob/1.5.3/mousetrap.js#L1008)). But to fire change detection after each async event the instance should be instantiated **inside the angular [zone](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)**. You have two options to achieve this:

1. Use dependency injection:

```ts
bootstrap(App, [provide(Mousetrap, { useFactory: () => new Mousetrap() }) ]);

// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  // ...
})
export class App {
  constructor(@Inject(Mousetrap) mousetrap) {
    this.mousetrap = mousetrap;
    // ...
  }
  //...
}
```

2. Just create instance of `Mousetrap` inside of the constructor:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  // ...
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.mousetrap = new Mousetrap();
    // ...
  }
  //...
}
```

In both cases you will have the ability to use the mousetrap instance like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.mousetrap.bind('i', () => this.incrementMode()); // It works now!!!
  // ...
}
```

**Now you don't need to use `ngZone.run()` in every `bind` call**. In case of dependency injection you also can use this `mousetrap` instance in any component/service of your application (not only in `App` component).

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aozEWICLhPzWud3k0ISq?p=preview). I use dependency injection there.

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution. Would it work for every/most libs out there?

Comment: @EricMartinez Well, there are too many js libraries with absolutely crazy implementations. So I definitely would not guarantee that this will work for every/most libraries. But basic principle is simple: you have to make sure that "async related" functions (such as `addEventListener`) was called inside angular zone - that's all.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Now I finally understand Savkin's statements: "Angular 2 uses Zone.js to know when this check is required. This means that you do not need to call scope.$apply to integrate with third-party libraries." -- from [The Core Concepts of Angular 2](http://victorsavkin.com/post/118372404541/the-core-concepts-of-angular-2) blog post, the ZONES section.  I had this on my to-be-figured-out/I-don't-understand list for quite some time.  (I assume the Angular 2 equivalent of Angular 1's scope.$apply is ApplicationRef.tick().  But we don't need that if we use this technique.)

Comment: @MarkRajcok You're very welcome. I'd say angular2's `ApplicationRef.tick()` is kind of equivalent to angular1's `$rootScope.$digest()`, `ngZone.run(cb)` is kind of equivalent to `$rootScope.$apply(cb)` and `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` is kind of equivalent to `$scope.$digest()`.

Answer (score 9):

If `MouseTrap` is something outside Angular you might need to inject `NgZone` and run your code like

```
  Mousetrap.bind('i', () => this.ngZone.run(() => this.incrementMode()));
```

Comment: Thanks for an information about NgZone, I made it work like this `Mousetrap.bind('i', () => this.ngZone.run(() => this.incrementMode())); `

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) Updated my answer.