# Angular 2 not updating when array is updated

Tags: angular

I have a service that fetches some objects via firebase. It then populates an array which should then prompt angular to update the DOM with an *ngFor statement, but it doesn't work. Code as follows:

`TeachersService`

```
    import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Teacher} from './teacher.ts';

@Injectable()
export class TeachersService {

  private firebaseURL: string;
  private teachersRef: Firebase;

  constructor() {
    this.firebaseURL = "https://xyz.firebaseio.com/teachers";
    this.teachersRef = new Firebase(this.firebaseURL);
  }

  getTeachers() {

    this.teachersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

      var tempArr = new Array(snapshot.numChildren());
      // this.teachers = snapshot.val();
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        var teacher = {
          name: data.key(),
          position: data.val().stilling
        }
        tempArr.push(teacher);
      });
      // this.teachers = tempArr;
      console.log(tempArr);
      return Promise.resolve(tempArr);
    });

    return Promise.resolve([]);
  }
}
```

And `Teachers`

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit, View} from 'angular2/core';

import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

import {TeachersService} from '../../services/teachers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'teachers',
  templateUrl: './components/teachers/teachers.html',
  providers: [TeachersService]
})


export class TeachersCmp implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  private firebaseURL: string;
  private teachersRef: Firebase;
  public teachers: Array<any>;
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _teachersService: TeachersService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateTeachersArr();
  }

  populateTeachersArr() {
    this._teachersService.getTeachers().then(teachers => this.teachers = teachers);
  }
```

}

`Teachers.html`

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#teacher of teachers">
        <strong>{{teacher.name}}</strong>: {{teacher.position}}
      </li>
```

I suspect this has to do with change detection (or at least my understanding of it). But I don't know how to prompt ng2 to detect the array update. If I create a static array like: `[1,2,3,4]` the *ngFor statement correctly works and displays it like it should in the DOM.

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2/34593821#34593821

Comment: It definately does @GünterZöchbauer. But being a bit thick, could you possibly provide an example of how to implement that?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the way you use promises within the `getTeachers` function (see my answer) and isn't related to change detection...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find a bit strange the way you use promises. It should be the reason of your problem. As a matter of fact, you return a promise resolved with an empty array. This array is directly used within the `then` method on the other side. When the `value` event is received, you return another promise within the callback which is never used.

I think you should return a promise and resolve it when the values are received within the callback for the `value` event.

Here is the refactoring I would propose within the `getTeachers` method to fix your problem:

```
getTeachers() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.teachersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var tempArr = new Array(snapshot.numChildren());
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        var teacher = {
          name: data.key(),
          position: data.val().stilling
        }
        tempArr.push(teacher);
      });
      resolve(tempArr);
    });
  });
}
```

**Edit**

After having some tests with your code on Firebase, it found out where the problem is. In fact, using promises isn't possible here since they are only called once. I mean the callback specified within the `then` method will be called only for the first `value` event. This is a drawback of promises.

To go over this restriction, you need to use observables. Here is the refactored version of the `getTeachers` method:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
(...)
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TeachersService {
  (...)
  getTeachers() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.teachersRef.on("value", snapshot => {
        var tempArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          var teacher = {
            name: data.key(),
            position: data.val().stilling
          }
          tempArr.push(teacher);
        });
        observer.next(tempArr);
      }
    });
  }
```

Within the component you can call the `getTeachers` method like this:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    (...)
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#teacher of teachers">
        <strong>{{teacher.name}}</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [ TeachersService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  (...)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateTeachersArr();
  }

  populateTeachersArr() {
    this._teachersService.getTeachers().subscribe(teachers =>
      this.teachers = teachers;
    );
  }
}
```

or go further by leveraging the `async` pipe (which will directly manages the observable object):

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    (...)
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#teacher of (teachers | async)">
        <strong>{{teacher.name}}</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [ TeachersService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  (...)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateTeachersArr();
  }

  populateTeachersArr() {
    this.teachers = this._teachersService.getTeachers();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry , thanks for your response. I'm afraid this produces the same outcome, i.e. no displayed data. I think that Gunther's proposal that it might have to do with the same issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2/34593821#34593821 is correct, I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your problem with Firebase tomorrow... I'll keep you informed ;-)

Comment: I think the solution that works on my side ;-) It's because of a limitation of promises. You should use observables instead. I updated my answer with working code. Feel free to tell if it fixes your problem.