# Angular 4 does not update an array when I push some data from a response after post

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have a **POST** method that the user will post an data to the server. The **POST** method is successfully working but I don't want to refresh my page after posting instead I want to update the array that I am looping through.

I want to update that array using the `push` method of an **array** base from the response of the post. My end goal here is to update the **posts** without refreshing the page like a real time update.

So here is what I have done so far.

```
posts: any = [];
fake_post: any = [];
success: boolean = false;
```

In my **constructor**

```
events.subscribe('post:created-successfully', (data) => {
      const promise = Promise.resolve(data)
      promise.then(() => this.success = true).then(() => this.fake_post = [])
      .then(() => setTimeout(() => { this.success = false }, 1000))
      .then(data => this.posts.push(data))
      .then(() => console.log(this.posts))
    });
```

and in my `submit()` method:

```
submit() {
    this.showLoader();
    if (this.form.value.title && this.form.value.author) {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.data = this.form.value;
      console.log(this.data);
      this.view.dismiss( this.data );
      this.postApiProvider.createPost(this.data).then((response : addReponse) => {
        console.log('Provider response', response);
        this.data = response;
      })
      .then(() => this.events.publish('post:created-successfully', this.data))
      .then(() => this.presentToast(this.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } else {
      console.log('Something went wrong.')
    }
  }
```

when I want `console.log` the **array** after the `push` method of an array this is what I got:

```
0
:
{title: "Async and Await", author: "Jayz", id: 1}
1
:
{title: "Promises", author: "Jayz", id: 2}
2
:
{title: "Callbacks", author: "Jayz", id: 3}
3
:
{title: "1234", author: "1234", id: 4}
4
:
135
```

That `indexOf` 4 id in the array is the post that I had created but I didn't return an object.

So how would I deal with this?

And as a bonus how can I refactor my **promises** using **async and await**?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Observable instead of promise and subscribe to them.
Refer the below thread for a possible solution:
[Angular 2 not updating when array is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598054/angular-2-not-updating-when-array-is-updated)

Comment: Thanks! I will use observables instead.

Comment: Btw I would like to ask. Why my array push isn't working that just return the same exact object with the existing ones. So yea I get a new GET request and the page didn't refresh but there's a little flickering.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reflect the data changes on the template, you need to use detect changes,

```
 constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
```

and apply the following once you push the data

```
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
```