# Prevent a native browser event ( like scroll ) from firing change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm binding an scroll event to capture the scroll and do something with it, I've created a directive like bellow :

So I have simple directive which has nothing but :

```
      constructor ( private el : ElementRef ,
                        private renderer : Renderer ) {
              this.domAdapter = new browser.BrowserDomAdapter();
              this.ruler      = new Ruler( this.domAdapter );
      }
      ngAfterViewInit () : any {
              this.renderer.listenGlobal( 'window' , 'scroll' , ()=> {
                  console.log( 'scrolling' );
              } );
              return undefined;
      }
```

This is working fine , expect that I can see that it fires a change detection on scroll in all of my application.

This is inside one of my components :

```
     private  aFunction () {
             console.log( 'change detected !!!' );
     }
```

I have `aFunction` in a template somewhere in some component :

```
       <div>{{ aFunction() }}</div>
```

Previously, `aFunction` was getting fired off, only if I updated some input or clicked on a button , but now , it's getting that change detection on scroll!!!
So my scrolling experience  is laggy because of this !.

This is the normal behavior of Angular2 , all the events should fire change Detection , but I want to exclude my scroll event from this rule .

In a nutshell , how to define a event in Angular2 and turn of it's ability to fire change detection and make it manual.

I'm looking for :

```
    this.renderer.listenGlobalButDontFireTheChangeDetection
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can offer you several hacks to do that:

1) Just set detection strategy to OnPush on your component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

The corresponding plunkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/NPHQqEmldC1z2BHFCh7C?p=preview

2) Use zone.runOutsideAngular together with the native window.addEventListener:

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=> {
    console.log( 'scrolling' );
  });
});
```

See also plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/6Db1AIsTEGAirP1xM4Fy

3) Use zone.runOutsideAngular together with new instance of [EventManager](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/EventManager-class.html) like this:

```
import { DomEventsPlugin, EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
   const manager = new EventManager([new DomEventsPlugin()], new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false}));
   manager.addGlobalEventListener('window','scroll', (e) => {
     console.log( 'scrolling' ); 
   });
});
```

The plunkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/jXBlM4fONKSNc7LtjChE?p=preview

I'm not sure that this is the right approach. Maybe it helps you in advancing... :)

**Update:**

Answer on this question: [View is not updated on change in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2) gave me an idea for the third solution.
Second solution is working because window was created outside of the angular zone. You can't do just:

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  this.renderer.listenGlobal( 'window' , 'scroll' , ()=> {
      console.log( 'scrolling' );
  } ); 
});
```

It won't work because this.renderer was created inside angular zone. http://plnkr.co/edit/UKjPUxp5XUheooKuKofX?p=preview

I dont't know how to create a new instance Renderer(DomRenderer in our case) so i just created new instance EventManager outside of working zone and with new instance NgZone.

Comment: thanks mate , I can't use the first one , because I don't want to change all of my components change detection strategy, second and third one looks exactly like what I want , can you please elaborate more on them ? What's their difference?

Comment: This solved my problem , both second and third is working fine , what's the difference ?
I wanted to use Renderer to make my code web worker friendly, which one of your answer is more like using Renderer and why ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to write soon

Comment: Does this work in Angular 2? I tried the 2nd method and my page still firing change detection when I scroll

Comment: @JoãoSilva Please create plunker to reproduce

Comment: I can't really reproduce since my data is loaded from a database, but I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011290/angular-2-performance-issue-rendering/45012198?noredirect=1#comment77000472_45012198

Comment: @JoãoSilva Just create mocked data that will be used in your minimal example

Comment: Solution 1) does not work because angular will fire change detection on any dom event