# angular2 events lead to check data change

Tags: angular

I'm using a Jquery plugin in my angular2 project.
It has a serious performance problem if the plugin has an event like `$(window).mousemove()` or  `setInterval(function(){}, 10)`. Because zone.js has hooks to html events, the page always checks data changes. My cpu is running very high.

Comment: Read about OnPush

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent a native browser event ( like scroll ) from firing change detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315781/prevent-a-native-browser-event-like-scroll-from-firing-change-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NgZone` to make code run inside or outside of Angulars zone.

Outside for performance reasons, inside to ensure Angular gets notified that change detection has to be run when properties of a component, model, or service are modiefied:

```ts
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
  zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    $(window).mousemove()...;
    setInterval(() => {}, 10);
  })
}

onMouseMove() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.someProp = 'someValue';
    this.router.navigate(....)
  });
}
```

Comment: ngZone.runOutsideAngular is working  doCheck call once. but if the route jumps doCheck always call.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the route jumps doCheck"?

Comment: I don't get how routing is related to your question.

Comment: from router '/a' to router '/b' runOutsideAngular is not work.
refresh '/b' runOutsideAngular is work

Comment: That's why I added ` this.router.navigate(....)` as example inside `this.zone.run()`. `router.navigate()` depends on change detection to happen. With `runOutsideAngular()` updating the view won't work.

Comment: Maybe I have a mistake description :(.  I mean that if I signal access /b, runOutsideAngular works. But if I jump from '/a'(another page) to '/b', then runOutsideAngular doesn't work. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't know how you use `runOutsideZone` or how you jump from `/a` to `/b`.

Comment: Component template [routerLink]="'/b"' ....  class BComponent(){ constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){  } ngAfterViewInit(){ this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(()=>{  echarts.init()  }) }  }

I access page b via http://xxxxxx/#/b, then runOutsideAngular works. If I jump from page a (via click a link) to page b, runOutsideAngular doesn't work. :(

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? (Plunker has an Angular2 template).

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) { this.mousemove.emit(event); }
```

instead `$(window).mousemove()`

will increase your performance