# How can I make Facebook Javascript SDK work with Angular 2 and Zone?

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, zonejs

I'm trying to build an authentication service for my angular2 app using FB Javascript SDK, however, the fact that the method `FB.login` (`window.FB.login`) is "out of the [Zone](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)" is breaking the "auto render thing" on my webapp. It happens because changes made as result of `FB.login` call don't update the view once they are "not monitored".

Right now, in order to make it work I'm manually defining the zone:

```
FB.login((response) => {
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
        ...
    }
}
```

however this isn't an "elegant solution" in my opinion.

Is there any other way to make it work [with FB Javascript SDK]?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34593821/893630

Comment: Hi @Michael, I'm already aware of that answer but I couldn't make it work in my case, maybe because `FB` is built on `window` (just guessing). Any thought on how to use dependency injection for FB SDK?

Comment: Perhaps try calling `FB.init` within your FB provider factory