# Update the view in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular

new in angular 2 and facing a problem here. Have an API which loads a js file in my project. The problem is, I have to use this js file and is not in my control to change it, basically, this js file has few methods which call an API via AJAX and return an array, but the way it returns it quite old fashion.
All I need is to update the view as soon the data comes in, tried many ways, but still cant get it worked. Any ideas how can I bind and update the view?

```js
import {Component, AfterContentInit} from "@angular/core";
import {IProduct} from "./product";
import {ProductService} from "./product.service";
declare var ExpressLibraryLoader: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements AfterContentInit{
    pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
    listFilter: string = '';
    products = [];
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void{
         //this._productService.getProducts().
           //   subscribe(products => this.products = products, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

        ExpressLibraryLoader.initialise({
            platformKey: 'xxx',
            brandID: 20,
            libraryUrl: "http://localhost/xxxxcx/",
            domainLaunchUrl: "http://localhost/xcxcxc/",
            success: function (ExpressLibrary) {
                let parameters =
                    {
                        languageCode: 'en',
                        gameProviderID: [7],
                        success: function (response) {

                            if (response.Status === "Success") {

                                //response.Result.Games.map(response => this.products = response);
                                this.products = response.Result.Games;
                                console.log(this.products)
                            } else {

                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        }
                    };
                ExpressLibrary.games.getDesktop(parameters);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You 're probably looking for ngZone. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use arrow function, `this` reference does not point to your class instance:

```
 success: function (ExpressLibrary) { ... }
 //change to
 success: (ExpressLibrary) => { ... }
 // or, quite funny you mentioned it
 success: function (ExpressLibrary) { ... }.bind(this)
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately. Trying with zone now, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, it seems that `this` in

```
success: function (response) {
           if (response.Status === "Success") {
             this.products = response.Result.Games;
             console.log(this.products)
           } }
```

has a different scope. So, solution is obvious and dead easy:

```
var that = this;

     var parameters =
          {
              //various parameters
              success: function(response){
                 if (response.Status === "Success") {
                    that.products = response.Result.Games;
                 } 
              },
              error: function () {

              }
           };
      ExpressLibrary.games.getDesktop(parameters);
```